# Slide-Out TextField Focus Pushing Content And Losing Transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

So, I am currently working on a website to practice web development, but I have ran into a little snag. I am wanting to be able to click the image "search-icon" and then have my text field slide out, which it does, but it is not focused and ready for the user to type. When I add the focus event it works, but it loses the transition and pushes my other content in my nav-holder aside for a second, which comes back. I am very confused as to why this is happening, and I would love some assistance with resolving my problem and understanding it a bit better.

Here is my HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="nav-holder">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WORK EXPERIENCE&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">WEB DEVELOPEMENT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">IT SUPPORT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">INTRODUCING ME</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT INFORMATION</a></li>
            </ul>


        </nav>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <input id="search-box" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>

        <img id="search-icon" src="img/searchicon.png"/>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</header>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-holder {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav {
    width: 72vw;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.active {
    color: lightgrey;
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: block;
    color: dimgrey;
    font-family: "Verdana";
}

nav a:hover {
    color: lightgrey;
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}

nav a:hover .one, nav a:hover .two {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}

nav ul ul {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black; 
    transform: translateY(-2em);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: lightgrey;
}

nav ul li:hover .one, nav ul li:hover .two  {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    float: none;
}

.one {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    height: 1px;
    width: 7px;
    transform: rotate(55deg);
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.two {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    height: 1px;
    width: 7px;
    transform: rotate(125deg);
    margin-left: -3.2px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#search-icon {
    float: right;
    max-height: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

#search-box {
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-right: -200px;
    line-height: 22px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
}

#search-box:focus {
    caret-color: lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
}

#search-box.active {
    margin-right: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    to {
        color: lightgrey;
        background: transparent;
    }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

And here is my JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'search-icon') {
            $('#search-box').toggleClass('active');
            $('#search-box').focus();
        }
        else if (e.target.id == 'search-box') {
              $('#search-box').focusin();
        }
        else {
            $('#search-box').removeClass('active');
            $('#search-box').val("");
        }
    });  
});
```

Thank you for your assistance ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove overflow:hidden from `.nav-holder`. You than need to work on the layout of the navbar for responsiveness.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'search-icon') {
      $('#search-box').toggleClass('active');
      $('#search-box').focus();
    } else if (e.target.id == 'search-box') {
      $('#search-box').focusin();
    } else {
      $('#search-box').removeClass('active');
      $('#search-box').val("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-holder {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav {
  width: 72vw;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.active {
  color: lightgrey;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: block;
  color: dimgrey;
  font-family: "Verdana";
}

nav a:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}

nav a:hover .one,
nav a:hover .two {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

nav ul li:hover>a {
  color: lightgrey;
}

nav ul li:hover .one,
nav ul li:hover .two {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  float: none;
}

.one {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  height: 1px;
  width: 7px;
  transform: rotate(55deg);
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.two {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  height: 1px;
  width: 7px;
  transform: rotate(125deg);
  margin-left: -3.2px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#search-icon {
  float: right;
  max-height: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

#search-box {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: -200px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
}

#search-box:focus {
  caret-color: lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
}

#search-box.active {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
  to {
    color: lightgrey;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="nav-holder">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WORK EXPERIENCE&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">WEB DEVELOPEMENT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">IT SUPPORT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">INTRODUCING ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT INFORMATION</a></li>
      </ul>


    </nav>

    <form method="post" action="">
      <input id="search-box" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>

    <img id="search-icon" src="http://placehold.it/50/00ff00" />

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. Thank you much!